# How can I earn 100 reputation bonus

Tags: support, reputation

In the past I earned the 100 reputation bonus from the Stack Overflow website.

I am wondering if and when I can reach again the bonus from the Ask Different website of the community knowing that a I already have 364 points and so (364-100 = 264 earned in here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the 100 rep association bonus: you only get that once per site, when you sign up for a site and already have at least 200 rep on another SE site. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation for the official documentation on this:

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

There is also http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/ but this probably was more important when cross site associations were introduced than today.

Comment: Ok, I got that. I thought that I could earn 100 more for each website in which I obtained 200 rep.

Comment: It's not a way to earn rep per se. It's just a way to give you basic participation rights on all sites once you passed the limit on at least one.